#  how to give fill parent size width to dynamic editbox in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

hello everyone i have multiple dynamic edittext box.i want to give width to fill parent size.
hows to give fill parent width to edittext?
plz help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.FILL_PARENT
        ,ViewGroup.FILL_PARENT);
edittext.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: Or rather: ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.FILL_PARENT
        ,ViewGroup.WRAP_CONTENT);
edittext.setLayoutParams(lp);

to just fill the width